# Can i list all the element that has specific shared name in using selenium webDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

if I have many elements that have a specific  name like (me1,me2,me3,me4,me5,) can I get all the elements that its name contain "me" 
I try to do this :

```
List<WebElement> implantToBePlaced= driver.findElements(By.xpath("/table/tbody/tr/td/*[contains(@name,'mi')]"));
```

I need to list all the elements that have "mi" at the name field

The HTML page is : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8PyT.png)

Comment: Please do not link to screenshots of text, rather post the text as actual text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional slash at the start of your XPath.

`/node` - look for "node" element at the root of the document.

`//node` - look for "node" element anywhere in the document.